# Replace row values by max values in the group

Tags: r, group-by, max, dplyr

I have a data frame look like this

```
 a <- c(10,NA,30,40,NA,60,70,80,90,90,80,90,10,40)
 b <- c(l,k,l,l,k,l,l,l,k,k,l,l,k,l)
 c <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)
```

I want to group data frame by column 'b' and 'c', then replace row values in 'a' column by max value of each group. For example: the 1st and 2nd of the 'a' column would be replaced by 30. Here is my code:

```
 df%>%group_by(b, c)%>%mutate(a = max(a, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Other values are replaced by max value but not NA. I don't know why `mutate`function rewrite NA by `inf`. Here is the result I have with my code:

```
 a <- c(30,inf,30,80,inf,80,80,80,90,90,90,90,10,90)
```

But I want it like this:

```
 a <- c(30,30,30,80,80,80,80,80,90,90,90,90,10,90)
```

Comment: Can you try to make it clearer what you want to know?

Comment: I suppose it's too much to ask for reproducible code to be provided?

Comment: You should just be grouping by "c". Voting to close this.

Comment: `ave(a,c,FUN =function(x)max(x,na.rm = T))` No need to group by `b`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data are:

```
Tuong_df <- data.frame(
    c(10,NA,30,40,NA,60,70,80,90,90,80,90,10,40),
    c("l","l","l","l","l","l","l","l","k","k","k","k","k","k"),
    c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4))
names(Tuong_df) <- c("Var1","Var2","Var3")
```

You have to run the following code:

```
Tuong_df_mod <- Tuong_df %>% 
    group_by(Var2,Var3) %>% 
    mutate(Var1=max(Var1,na.rm=TRUE))
```

Anyway, for the near future, it should be better if you release reproducible code.

Comment: Please don't name a data.frame `df` as there is a function with this name and that can lead to very strange error messages, if anything goes wrong. Also, please don't abbreviate `na.rm=TRUE` to `na.rm=T`. If someone sets `T <- 0` for whatever reason, the working code will suddenly stop working.

Comment: That's true, I agree and re-edited my answer